# Has anyone tried using the bitbake-env utility lately?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Has anyone tried using the bitbake-env utility lately?

I do not see it installed:

```
[user@localhost build]$ which bitbake
~/YOCTO/oe_core_embedded/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake
[user@localhost build]$ which bitbake-env
/usr/bin/which: no bitbake-env in (/home/user/YOCTO/oe_core_embedded/poky/scripts:/home/user/YOCTO/oe_core_embedded/poky/bitbake/bin:/usr/libexec/python2-sphinx:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin)
[user@localhost build]$
```

As well I do not see it in the bitbake command listing:

```
[user@localhost poky]$ cd bitbake/bin
[user@localhost bin]$ ls -al
total 100
drwxrwxr-x. 2 user user  4096 Oct 18 12:49 .
drwxrwxr-x. 6 user user  4096 Oct 18 12:49 ..
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  2072 Nov 18 11:51 bitbake
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  7228 Oct 18 12:49 bitbake-diffsigs
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  2894 Oct 18 12:49 bitbake-dumpsig
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  4069 Oct 18 12:49 bitbake-layers
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  2109 Oct 18 12:49 bitbake-prserv
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  2128 Oct 18 12:49 bitbake-selftest
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user 17866 Oct 18 12:49 bitbake-worker
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user 13951 Oct 18 12:49 bitdoc
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  5813 Oct 18 12:49 git-make-shallow
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  8805 Oct 18 12:49 toaster
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 user user  4177 Oct 18 12:49 toaster-eventreplay
[user@localhost bin]$
```

It still exists/is listed in https://elinux.org/Bitbake_Cheat_Sheet from July 2016.

Answer (score 1):

`bitbake-env` is a third party utility, and not actually a part of the OpenEmbedded Core hence why you will not see it unless you specifically install it.  It is actually an 'improved' version of the `bitbake -e` flag for bitbake.

```
bash-4.3$ bitbake --help
Usage: bitbake [options] [recipename/target recipe:do_task ...]

    Executes the specified task (default is 'build') for a given set of target recipes (.bb files).
    It is assumed there is a conf/bblayers.conf available in cwd or in BBPATH which
    will provide the layer, BBFILES and other configuration information.

Options:
  ...
  -e, --environment     Show the global or per-recipe environment complete
                        with information about where variables were
                        set/changed.
```